# Conditional wrapping element in Svelte

Tags: svelte

Svelte rejects this syntax:

```
// conditional open link tag
{#if whatever}
  <a href="myurl">
{/if}

// 
// many lines of code for dynamic text output
//

// conditional close link tag
{#if whatever}
  </a>
{/if}
```

Svelte's compiler throws: `ParseError: Unexpected block closing tag` on the first conditional block, because it sees a `<a>` without a matching `</a>`.

This is a common need: something may need to become a hyperlink in some conditions but not in others, and the content within is far too complex to copy-paste so that it appears twice. I suppose the same thing could come up with any other html tag with opening and closing tags, where one wishes to conditionally add an html wrapper around something.

Certainly one could accomplish this either by creating a conditional component for every kind of html tag and slotting the inner code, or by moving the inner content to a function and injecting it into the DOM with `{@html...}`, but these are ungainly solutions for something so incredibly basic and simple.

This just seems like something the framework should provide. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case the solution is simple: Just *always* use an `<a>` and make the `href` conditional (a string or `undefined`). An `<a>` is *not* a link unless it actually has an `href`.

In general, you can create a generic wrapper component like this:

```html
<script>
  export let element;
  export let condition;
</script>

{#if condition}
  <svelte:element this={element} {...$$restProps}>
    <slot />
  </svelte:element>
{:else}
  <slot />
{/if}
```

```html
<Wrapper element="a" condition={...}>
  <!-- contents -->
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: I want to avoid the generic wrapper, as in my case it would get invoked thousands of times in one screen and I'm concerned about performance with so many bindings. I need this link only a tiny minority of cases. I tried the `<a></a>` without an `href` but the browser still interprets it as a link, and svelte's `on:click` still adds a listener.

Comment: If you have event handlers, you will of course have to make them conditional as well. What do you mean by it being interpreted as a link? If that were the case, it would not adhere to the specification.

Comment: I think bootstrap is overriding the default behavior, and making every `<a>` look like a valid link even if it's not. I was able to get the behavior I wanted by adding a conditional class where the CSS turned off the color, pointer and mouse events. I still have an extra element I don't need 99% of the time, but it's lighter-weight than any other option.

Comment: In Svelte 5, snippets will help with the creation of conditional wrappers without a separate component ([preview docs](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/docs/snippets)).